# Android java SHA256 and C# sha256 give different values

Tags: java, c#, android, encode, sha256

Android java SHA256 and C# sha256 give different values. I want java to be same as c#.

c# code:

```
private static string _getHashSha256(string inputString)
{
    string hashString = string.Empty;
    using (SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        byte[] bytes = UTF32Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(inputString);
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        foreach (byte x in hash)
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
    }
    return hashString;
}

input "111", result "f4b5625de0c6abd88521b87d39f5a4fe33935f27c4ac38a63575ad43d36c7fbb"
```

android java code:

```
String password="111";
MessageDigest digest=null;
String hash;
try {
    digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-32"));

    hash = bytesToHexString(digest.digest());

    Log.i("sha256", hash);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    z = "hash code error: " + e1.getMessage();
}

input is "111". result "12215d42454c57aa1039367b66509e53dcd2d6f9a6e80f9d00b2439ea7ebd43f"
```

please help me guys!

Comment: What are the different hashes you get?

Comment: Please confirm that you start with the same sequence of bytes to be hashed. Providing good [mre] for single problem is ideal for SO questions - i.e. remove all string-related code and show byte arrays as constant values.

Comment: c# result for "111" is "f4b5625de0c6abd88521b87d39f5a4fe33935f27c4ac38a63575ad43d36c7fbb". java result for "111" is "12215d42454c57aa1039367b66509e53dcd2d6f9a6e80f9d00b2439ea7ebd43f"

Comment: thanks guys. I found. the problem was when java converts string to bytes by utf-32, there is additional 4 bytes preceded. it changed resulting sha256

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
I found the problem was when java converts string to bytes by utf-32, there is additional 4 bytes preceded. it changed resulting sha256.
So I removed that initial 4 bytes as follows:

```
String password="111";
MessageDigest digest=null;
String hash;

byte[] bbb = user_pass.getBytes("UTF-32");
byte[] ccc = new byte[bbb.length - 4];
System.arraycopy(bbb, 4, ccc, 0, bbb.length - 4);

digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digest.update(ccc);

hash_password = bytesToHexString(digest.digest());
```

Comment: In other words there's a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf32encoding.getpreamble?view=net-6.0 at the start.